# How to capitalize first letter of word in php without ucfirst() function

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to capitalize the first letter of word in php without using ucfirst() function But i am not able do it , but i am struggling with this. Please tell me its answer.

```
<?php

   $str ="the resources of earth make life possible on it";
   $str[0] = chr(ord($str[0])-32);  
   $length = strlen($str);
  
   for($pos=0; $pos<$length; $pos++){
           if($str[$pos]==' '){
               $str[$pos+1] = chr(ord($str[$pos+1])-32);
       }
    }
   echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: In `chr(ord($str[0]-32));`, your close bracket is in the wrong place, try `chr(ord($str[0])-32)`

Comment: You should clarify what functions you can not use.  chr() and ord() are functions.

Answer (score 3):

Without using the function `ucfirst`, you can do it like this:

```
$firstLetter = substr($word, 0, 1);
$restOfWord  = substr($word, 1);

$firstLetter = strtoupper($firstLetter);
$restOfWord  = strtolower($restOfWord);

print "{$firstLetter}{$restOfWord}\n";
```

To do it for each word, use `explode(' ', $string)` to get an array of words, or `preg_split('#\\s+#', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` for better results.

**I would advise against** just subtracting 32 from the first character of the next word:

- you do not know it is a letter
- you do not know it isn't already capitalized
- you do not know *it exists*
- you do not know *it is not another space*

At the very least check that its `ord()` value lies between `ord('A')` and `ord('Z')`.

To do this all without case-changing functions, you'd do

```
$text = implode(' ',
    array_map(
        function($word) {
            $firstLetter = substr($word, 0, 1);
            if ($firstLetter >= 'a' && $firstLetter <= 'z') {
                $firstLetter = chr(ord($firstLetter)-32);
            }
            $restOfWord  = substr($word, 1);
            $len = strlen($restOfWord);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                if ($restOfWord[$i] >= 'A' && $restOfWord[$i] <= 'Z') {
                    $restOfWord[$i] = chr(ord(restOfWord[$i])+32);
                }
            }
            return $firstLetter . $restOfWord;
        },
        preg_split('#\\s+#', $originalText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
    )
);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm pretty sure that the question is asking how to do this without any functions, or at least any case changing functions.

Comment: @gview You may be right. Added the function-poor case to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

as such...

```php
$str ="the resources of earth make life possible on it";
$words=array_map(static fn($a) => ucfirst($a), explode(' ', $str));

echo implode(' ', $words);
```

with ord and chr

```php
$ordb=ord('b'); //98

$capitalB=chr(98-32); //B

$ordA=ord('a'); //97

$caiptalA=chr(97-32); //A

//so 




function capitalize(string $word)
{

$newWord = '';

$previousCharIsEmpty = true;
$length = strlen($word);

for ($a = 0; $a < $length; $a++) {
    if ($word[$a] === ' ') {
        $newWord .= ' ';
        $previousCharIsEmpty = true;
    } else {
        if ($previousCharIsEmpty === true) {
            $ord = ord($word[$a]);
            $char = chr($ord - 32);
            $newWord .= $char;
            $previousCharIsEmpty = false;
        } else {
            $newWord .= $word[$a];
        }
        $previousCharIsEmpty = false;
    }

return $newWord;
   
}

$word = 'this for example by dilo abininyeri';
echo capitalize($word);
```

and output

```
This For Example By Dilo Abininyeri
```

Comment: Question asks how to do this without php functions.

Comment: I will send tomorrow another example without PHP functions

Comment: Code is very more

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do this without any function. We have to use some function. Like you have applied the for-loop and for strlen function.

```
<?php

   $str ="the resources of earth make life possible on it";
   $str[0] = chr(ord($str[0])-32);  
   $length = strlen($str);
  
   for($pos=0; $pos<$length; $pos++){
           if($str[$pos]==' '){
               $str[$pos+1] = chr(ord($str[$pos+1])-32);
       }
    }
   echo $str;
?>
```